# Python Flask "The configuration file does not exist." accessing sub-path

Tags: python, flask

I am deploying Flask on **CPanel**, and basic configurations are working correctly,
up to the point that I can access home route, defined as:

```py
@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/")
def home():
   return "This is home page, blah blah blah"
```

The site can be thought of, as being accessed at
https://sub-domain.main-domain.com/base-url,

thus, home page is accessed as *https://sub-domain.main-domain.com/base-url/* and that works perfectly.

**Problem**

So, the issue comes when I access any other route, other than the slash("/"),
in the above example, for instance, accessing

*https://sub-domain.main-domain.com/base-url/home*,

doesn't seem to work at all, and results in

`The configuration file does not exist.` error.

Any possible help would be kindly appreciated. my **passenger_wsgi.py** is configured as:

```py
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
base_dir = u'/home/cpaneusername/base-dir'
if base_dir not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [base_dir] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from app import website as application
```

Nevertheless, thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest resolving the issue is to change the base URL of your Python app and remove any sub-folders from it. For example, just keep it that way:

https://sub-domain.main-domain.com/

And try again.

Otherwise, you might want to change the /home route of your app to this one instead:

@app.route("/base-url/home")

If none of the above works, then make sure that you have the correct .htaccess rules in place to forward the requests properly to your app, but I assume you already have considering the fact that you are able to access the / of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I tried moving the Python app and other supporting modules to **/public** folder, and in the **wsgi** file, I imported as

```py
from public.app import website as application
```

There, it worked.